# How to reinitiate or reload "echoed" drop down list?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to reload this HTML dropdown list after some database details get changed. Any ideas?

Note: `ddl_my_items.reload();` is not working.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//populates the ddl of items
$items = $dal->get_items() or die(mysql_error());

echo "<select id='ddl_my_items'>";
echo "<option value=''></option>";
foreach ($items as $item){
echo "<option value='$item->item_name'>$item->item_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to fetch the contents of the list again.

Comment: may you please elaborate? i can't figure the way of using ajax in this scenario. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest if you include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

create a php file ajax.php that only echoes the dropdown list contents:

```
<?php
//populates the ddl of items
$items = $dal->get_items() or die(mysql_error());

echo "<option value=''></option>";
foreach ($items as $item){
    echo "<option value='$item->item_name'>$item->item_name</option>";
}
```

Then, use the following javascript code:

```
$.get('ajax.php', function(result) {
    $('#ddl_my_items').html(result);
}
```

The function `$.get` sends an AJAX request (which is simply a HTTP request whose response can be received in javascript). The anonymous function is called as soon as the contents have been received.

`$('#ddl_my_items')` returns a jQuery object of the `select` element, and its `html` allow you to alter the element's content by passing the html code you've just received by the ajax call.

Comment: Simply put the three lines of javascript in a function and call that function everytime you want to refresh the list.